# Where I can find frame specification?

Tags: ethernet, wireshark

When I capture from wireshark traffic I can see data like this
[image: frame data]

Where I can see the specification of each field?

When I read wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame  there is nothing like this. Also in wiki I can see that there should be for example MAC adresess. Where are they?

Comment: The IEEE has the specifications for the IEEE LAN protocols (ethernet, token ring, Wi-Fi, etc.). Most of what you see there is not actually part of the frame, but of meta data created by Wireshark. You need to scroll down more to the `Ethernet II` section to see more of the frame itself, and the window below that will have the actual bits (in hex) of the frame.

Comment: just too add: if the information is between square brackets, it's added by wireshark and not part of the spec

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Ethernet frame is (mostly) defined in IEEE 802.3 Clause 3. The official standards can be downloaded from [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68). There are countless other sources on the frame formats as well.